# magento2 i have errror in customize theme

Tags: magento, less, magento2, magento2.4

**app/design/vendor/theme_name/Magento_Catalog/web/css/source/_module.less in file i have some changes in less file then compilation some error like some variable not define and i try replace file _module.less in to _extend.less file then no error in compilation**

**i try to add _moduele.less file then**

**Compilation from source: /var/www/html/magento2demo/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-m.less
variable @product-name-link__color is undefined in file /var/www/html/magento2demo/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/Cogent/Cogent_Theme/en_US/css/source/_extends.less in _extends.less on line 294, column 31
292|         > a {
293|             .lib-link(
294|                 @_link-color: @product-name-link__color,
295|                 @_link-text-decoration: @product-name-link__text-decoration**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQDXW.png)

**i try _extend.less then work fine[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imsh0.png)**

what is diifrence between _extend.less and _module.less and when i use ??/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diffrenec between _extend.less and _module.less files

_extend.less

we use _extend.less file when you want to use parent CSS and want add more CSS

_module.less

_module.less file is used to when we want to completely newly theme at that case we cannot use previous declare variable. we need to declare that variable again into theme variable file.

You can check more guide into following link
[Read more](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_approach.html#simple_extend)